# Check the state of buttons-checkbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I want to make a checkbox that looks like a button: when it is checked, the button looks pressed; when it is unchecked, the button looks unpressed.

As I use bootstrap, naturally I think of using `data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"`. But It does not seem very practical to verify the state of the checkbox. For example, `.prop('checked')` does not seem to work in the following code.

```js
  $('#input-checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($("#input-checkbox").prop('checked')) {
      alert("yes");
    } else {
      alert("no");
    }
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" id="input-checkbox">INPUT</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `value` attribute to your button. I changed `btn-default` to `btn-primary` and added a normal button on the side to state the difference.

```js
$('#input-checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($("#input-checkbox").attr('value')=="checked"){
      $("#input-checkbox").attr('value','notchecked');
      $("#input-checkbox").removeClass('active');
    } 
    else {
      $("#input-checkbox").attr('value','checked');
      $("#input-checkbox").addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

```css
.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active" value="checked" id="input-checkbox">INPUT</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> NPUT</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It does work... But I am quite surprised that we have to add a self-defined attribute "value" for a "checkbox".

Comment: well , we could make it work by other method too. but toggling classes are not good when we need to hold a state while other functions or events take place. can you please accept the answer then.

Comment: No problem to accept the answer. Additionally, it seems that `$("#input-checkbox").removeClass('active');` and `$("#input-checkbox").addClass('active');` are not necessary.

Comment: I realise that `$(this).hasClass('active')` could be a check, rather than adding a self-defined attribute `value`.